# Quickly check if two regular expressions share matches

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

say I have a list of regular expressions, which match filepaths:

```
{
   "list":[
      "^/foo/bar/baz/x",
      "^/foo/bar/baz/y"
      "^/foo/mon/choo$",
      ...
      "^/foo/.*"
   ]
}
```

Note that at runtime, this will happen:

```
let regexes = list.map(function(l){
       return new RegExp(l);
});
```

I need to create a routine to quickly check if two or more of the regular expressions match the same input.

Is there a way to quickly check if an imaginary/potential filepath would match more than one regular expression in the list?

For example, the regular expression /foo/.*  will match the first 3 items, and therefore that represents an error in my program.

Use case: the user is expected to create a list of regular expressions, but they have to be exclusive regular expressions which do not share any matches.

I could check this with actual input, but I am wondering if there is a way to check this with theoretical input as well. (I am hoping that latter would be faster).

**The "hard" way:** I have a list of files. For each file I check to see if it matches any of the regular expressions in the list. If it matches more than 1 in the list, I throw an error.

The problem with the hard way is that I would like to validate the list before using any real input data.

Comment: note that because these are filepaths, I am hoping there is some clever way to avoid some factorial comparison as well.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do it automatically, though you know that if the regexes don't include `^` and `$` they could all match a single string: every regex in your sample list would match the string `"/foo/bar/baz/x/foo/bar/baz/y/foo/mon/choo"`. Many regexes could match an infinite number of input strings, so I think expecting the user to create mutually exclusive regexes is too strict - why does it matter if they do?

Comment: yeah let me add ^ to the begging of each item in the list for clarification, thanks

Comment: *I am wondering if there is a way to check this with theoretical input* There might be ways to check if two regexps could both theoretically match some input, or if they could never both match any input, but solving this general problem is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using an array, it's possible to have duplicates of the exact regex, so maybe you want to use an object with keys instead or just set it.

Along with that, you could actually use the regex themselves to test each other. In my example below I'm only checking `.*` or `.+` but if you really want to be comprehensive, you could run each regex against every other regex. Though I didn't do this because it might have a really long run time, but that's up to you.

```js
var list = [
  "/foo/bar/baz/x",
  "/foo/bar/baz/y",
  "/foo/mon/choo$",
  "/foo/.*"
];

var error_list = [...list, "/foo/mon/choo$"];
let set = new Set(error_list);

console.log(set.length === list.length, "\"if false it means there's duplicates\"");

var regexes = [];

for (var regex of list){
  if (regex.match(/\.(\*|\+)/)){
    regexes.push(regex);
  }
}

loop:
for (var regex of regexes){
  var r = new RegExp("^"+regex);
  for (let test of list){
    if (test.match(r) && regex !== test){
      console.log(test, "this matched");
      // break loop;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Testing the regexes on each other doesn't tell you whether they might each match some other string. If you remove `"/foo/.*"` from the list then none of the others match against each other but they could all test positive against a single input string.

Comment: @nnnnnn well it depends on how OP implements it. Maybe he's just checking that each regex don't match each other, idk. That's how I interpretted the question.

Comment: From the question: *"...check if two or more of the regular expressions match the same input. Is there a way to quickly check if an imaginary/potential filepath would match more than one regular expression in the list?"* - 
Both of those sentences talk about matching something not in the list.

Comment: @nnnnnn I suppose, but from the editted question maybe he's already going to sanitise it a bit, so it's actually part of a larger expression. So the final regex is `new RegExp("^" + regex)` or anything else in lieu of `^`. People tend to ask assuming the answerer already knows the question/intention. If it's not the right answer, perhaps you can answer.

Comment: I swear I added this comment already => RegExp.prototype.exec(str) works on a string, not a regex. The regex passed to exec will be coerced to a string literal.

Comment: @AlexanderMills - you did add it already, I saw it. 
Don't know what happened to it. Anyway, the items in your array are strings so they don't need to be coerced when passed to .exec(). 
(And speaking of coercion, you can't coerce something to be a string *literal*, literals only exist in source code.)

Comment: thanks glad you saw my comment before, that is weird. Anyway..I think you a missing a key detail. Every string in the list needs to be interpreted as a Regex, not a string literal. So I cannot extract one as a Regex and compared it to remainder as strings. I will make that clear in the question.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes and that's what the comparison does. It's basically seeing if the found regex is a superset of the identified string. If you have `/foo/.*` then anything that begins with `/foo/` will be a subset of `/foo/.*`, thus you have duplicates. Setting the array means that all strings have to be unique, quickly eliminating one problem.

Comment: @AlexanderMills - I realise each item has to be converted to a regex for use, but still you do initially have them as strings so that means you can do string-based operations at the point where you're trying to do the no-duplicates validation (which may or may not help solve the problem, but it is an option).